# How to get the youtube video timing from it's id in Laravel 5.1?

Tags: php, youtube-api, laravel-5.1

I need to display the timing of the youtube video in my view. Can anyone help me to proceed? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are lot of php libraries for youtube. You can use one of those or you can call to youtube api directly using guzzle. Using a library is easier. try `getVideoInfo` method in this [library](https://github.com/alaouy/Youtube)

**Direct Youtube API**

`GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=contentDetails&id={VideoId}&key={YOUR_API_KEY}`

[Try Youtube API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list#try-it)